# Ordering in a MVC and Repository Pattern structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern, roles

I am developing an application with ASP.NET MVC and repository pattern with a [service layer](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs) that exposes some funcionalities in a web service used by another application. Sometimes I get confused about the roles in each layer. One of my doubts is about ordering lists of objects to show on the view.

**I should order the lists in the view, controller, service or repository?**

As this is a '*way of show the items*', I guess this is a view responsability, but i use the same list with same ordering in another application through the web service. So, this ordering should be on service layer? Or I should order in repository, by query, to optimize the ordering?

Comment: I believe that your repository should return a IQueryable, and your service apply order, filter, groupping, etc...

Comment: I wouldn't use Repository for querying. I'd use separate Query handlers otherwise your repository just gets polluted with queries. I find using repositories only when updating data makes code more maintanable. Something like this http://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92

Comment: Well, now i am applying order on service layer, but I reached a case of two views shows the same list with different ordering and i get confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're truly following the repository pattern, your repository should consist of methods merely like: `Get`, `Update`, `Delete`, etc. FWIW, this is why I have a personal distaste for using the repository pattern with Entity Framework: all you're doing is proxying from your repository to EF and adding an unnecessary layer of complexity.

Your service, however, *should* have explicit methods that return a particular dataset with no further need of evaluation. However, ordering is a bit of an abnormality. You could either fetch an ordered dataset directly from the database or order the in-memory structure, and ordering is one of those things that are pretty view specific. Additionally, you may even want to order the same dataset in two different ways, which would require an extra unnecessary query if you're relying on the DAL layer alone.

I would personally say that for the most part, ordering should happen in your controller action, but if there's something that should always be returned in a particular order, then just have your service layer return it ordered already. You could also always just add a parameter to your service method to allow passing an ordering scheme, which buys you ability to customize this in your action but still have it handled by the service:

```
public IEnumerable<Something> GetSomething(Func<IQueryable<Something>, IOrderedQueryable<Something>> orderBy = null)
{
    ...

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        return orderBy(query).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
service.GetSomething(m => m.OrderBy(o => o.Field1).ThenBy(o => o.Field2))
```